# What is a Tellygraph Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Tellygraph Word™.

Can you tell me how to get a word that conforms to the rule?

[image: Examples of Tellygraph Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Tellygraph Words™,Not Tellygraph Words™
ANVIL,FORGE
ANXIETY,STRESS
FILTHY,DIRTY
HAMLET,HOVEL
INFLAME,IGNITE
INHALE,BREATHE
KNIFE,BLADE
NATIVE,LOCAL
NEAT,CLEAN
TWINKLE,SHINE
VITAL,CRITICAL
VIXEN,HARLOT
WEALTHY,WELL-OFF
WHINE,FUSS
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Tellygraph Word™ is, in essence,

> a word containing no letters that are drawn using a curved line (`BCDGJOPQRSU`).

It's called a Tellygraph Word™ because

> if you look at the top edge or the bottom edge of the word, the letters can be interpreted as Morse Code.

For example,

> The word **`ANVIL`**  The top edge of the word is $\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot - \centerdot$.  The bottom edge is $\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot\centerdot - -$  (The first five dots on the top are from the top of the `A`, the tops of the two arms of the `N`, and the tops of the two arms of the `V`.)

Comment: Wow, this answer is totally better than what I intended. The fact that it works is an accidental artifact of what I actually designed it to be. I searched for a puzzle that already covered this one and I couldn't find it but I strongly feel like one exists. If it does, would that make this question an accidental duplicate? You have answered first, validly, and better than OP. I'll leave it open a bit to see if someone else sees what I see or if the logical leap I built in was too large.

Comment: I wonder if there are words whose top/bottom edge encodes the word itself in morse code.

Comment: @xnor I think there can't be many of them.  Also, there might be some variations in encoding.  If you make an majuscule I as a straight line, then it's a dot, but if you make it with wide crossbars, it would be a dash. That issue aside, I think that the big problem would be that most letters' actual Morse Code is longer than their Tellygraph Morse Code, you'd end up with too much Morse Code.  That said, T is  -, U is ..-, so TUT is - ..-, which I guess would count.