# What is a CPO Word?™

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a CPO Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| CPO Words™ | Not CPO Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ANIMAL | BEAST |
| BULKY | HUGE |
| DEGRADE | DEMEAN |
| FEATHER | POULTRY |
| IGNITE | BLAZE |
| JEANS | SLACKS |
| MAY | JUNE |
| NERVOUS | ANXIOUS |
| PUBLIC | DISCRETE |
| REPLACE | DISPLACE |
| SPELUNKING | EXPLORING |
| UNSTABLE | TEETERING |
| VOICE | CRY |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
CPO Words™,Not CPO Words™  
ANIMAL,BEAST
BULKY,HUGE
DEGRADE,DEMEAN
FEATHER,POULTRY
IGNITE,BLAZE
JEANS,SLACKS
MAY,JUNE
NERVOUS,ANXIOUS
PUBLIC,DISCRETE
REPLACE,DISPLACE
SPELUNKING,EXPLORING
UNSTABLE,TEETERING
VOICE,CRY
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a CPO Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of CPO Words™, many more exist and can be found.

Hint:

> Let someone else do the searching.

Comment: OP, any hints??

Comment: I added a hint.

Comment: The hint makes me think of SEO, but I am unable to sort the words based on that criteria.

Comment: Is the acronym (CPO) helpful in solving this puzzle? Or will we only see what it meant afterwards?
The hint is not really helping me either so far...

Comment: I'd say so. It's a common use of the acronym, at least in the USA

Comment: @Matt Ah I see, I'm not a native English speaker myself, so I just looked up the abbreviation online and got about five or six different options. But, going over it again now, I guess the one related to used cars (or used stuff in general) is probably the most likely one.

Comment: @Levieux I can't disagree ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a CPO Word™ is one which has been

> used before in the What is a Word™/Phrase™ series either as a positive or negative example.

Examples are -

> ANIMAL : [What is an Anagrammable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42347/what-is-an-anagrammable-word/42355)
>  BULKY : [What is an Odious Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42142/what-is-an-odious-word)
>  DEGRADE : [What is a Spaced Out Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41720/what-is-a-spaced-out-word)
>  FEATHER : [What is a Perfect Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43173/what-is-a-perfect-word)
>  IGNITE : [What is a Tellygraph Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23465/what-is-a-tellygraph-word)
>  JEANS : [What is a Veteran Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42393/what-is-a-veteran-word/42396)
>  MAY : [What is an Inflated Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/what-is-an-inflated-word)
>  NERVOUS : [What is an Uptight™ Word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42253/what-is-an-uptight-word/42287)
>  PUBLIC : [What is an Explosive Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43189/what-is-an-explosive-word)
>  REPLACE : [What is a Conflicted Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/what-is-a-conflicted-word)
>  SPELUNKING : [What is an Energetic Transmitter Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/what-is-an-energetic-transmitter-word)
>  UNSTABLE : [What is a Rotary Club Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45504/what-is-a-rotary-club-word)
>  VOICE : [What is a Chaotic Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42256/what-is-a-chaotic-word)

They are called CPO words as this is an abbreviation for

> Certified Pre-owned  - credit for this is due to Levieux - who let someone else do the searching.